# How frequent are Scart-compatible CRT TVs in Japan?

Tags: japan, television

I’m about to move to Japan from central Europe. I am a retro-console (speed) gamer and have fitted most of my consoles with the required Scart cables for them to output an RGB signal. For speed purposes, I prefer playing on CRTs.

Considering CRTs are dated, I will probably be able to find lots to buy second-hand at a low price. What concerns me is that Japan is known to have its own JP-21 RGB standard which uses the same connector as Euroscart but a different pinout. Do CRTs exist in Japan which are capable of accepting Scart input and if so, how common are they? Or should I rather attempt to find a Scart to JP-21 converter because all TVs with that socket assume a JP-21 signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this after some time.

It was actually completely impossible to find any CRT TV. Furthermore, I was unable to locate any TV anywhere that had a Scart or JP-21 socket. Input choices were RCA, S-video or HDMI, essentially.

When I recently tried to sell my (bought second-hand) flat-screen TV I found out why: second-hand shops will not accept TVs older than 10 years, which essentially precludes any CRTs from existing on the second-hand market.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific purpose it might simply be much easier to buy a converter, especially since they aren't too expensive. For example see this one: https://www.retrogamingcables.co.uk/european-scart-to-japanese-scart-converter

Comment: Thanks. I actually soldered two passthrough converters myself using old SCART cables =)

Comment: Or get a SCART to HDMI converter and you're set.